# jQuery Exception on Heroku

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, heroku

I am using jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 for simple mobile app. Locally it's running great (Mac OSX Lion). When I deploy to Heroku, my app will not load in the browser. The dev tools (chrome) show me the following error in jQuery.js:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

[image]

Seems like what I'm doing is pretty strait forward. Could it be a problem with how the assets are being assembled once they are served from Heroku?

UPDATE: One additional not, this ONLY happens when I have the developer tools open in Chrome. I can close it, but I have another bug which i need the dev tools to see! Thanks for any leads.

Comment: Still haven't figured out why having the dev tools open caused the error. But I had a client-side mixpanel call interfering with my jquery mobile stuff. So that problem is solved, but I'm curious about this question, still..